# Are Firebase Functions safe to use

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

my Project is currently so build that all writing operations are handled by a Firebase function like createUser, followUserDirectly, acceptRequest or sendFollowRequest.

My first question is if the functions can be executed by an attacker outside my app and its logic.

The second is: Can the attributes that are passed to the function be modified outside of the intended logic? For example if the wrong user id is passed so that a completely different follow request will be accepted.

Comment: We can't say anything about whether your functions are secure without seeing them. But if they're HTTP-callable functions they won't be secured unless you've secured access to them yourself, as shown for example here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

If you expose any API to a webclient you have to assume it can be used outside of your webapplication aswell. It's then up to you to secure your API & apply the security you see is necessary. Firebase has good documentation & FAQ for you to make up your judgement if you see fit at https://firebase.google.com/

As to per your user-id question, refer to:

> Will it be safe to rely on Firebase, for the security of my app data from hackers?

Firebase implements [authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html) and [declarative security](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/quickstart.html) rules for security.